# How to create factors from factanal?

Tags: r, statistics

When performing a factor analysis using factanal the usual result is some loadings table plus several other information. Is there a direct way to use these loadings to create a matrix / data.frame of factors? For example to use them in regression analysis later on.

EDIT: the purpose of this is to obtain variables for subsequent modeling. I only know of factor scores – but suggestions / pointers to other terminology are welcome :)

EDIT2: Joris Meys answer answer is basically what I was asking for. Still though it moves my question towards a direction that might be better suited for statsoverflow, but I will keep it here for now, because the right group of people is the discussing the solution:

What´s the benefit of the regression based scores? The result of the product (ML) is highly correlated with the factors... Honestly I wonder why the difference is that big in my case?

```
 fa$scores # the correct solution
 fac <- m1 %*% loadings(fa) # the answer on your question
 diag(cor(fac,fa$scores))
 #returns:
Factor1   Factor2   Factor3 
0.8309343 0.8272019 0.8070837
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You asked how to use the loadings for construction of scores. Your solution is, although correct, not doing that. It's using a regression method (alternatively you can use Bartlett's method as well), and this uses the restriction that the scores are uncorrelated, centered around 0 and with variance = 1. These are hence not the same factors as one would obtain by using F = ML with F the factor matrix, M the original matrix and L the loading matrix.

A demonstration with the example from the help files :

```
v1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6)
v2 <- c(1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,3,4,3,3,3,4,6,5)
v3 <- c(3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,4,6)
v4 <- c(3,3,4,3,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,5,6,4)
v5 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,6,4,5)
v6 <- c(1,1,1,2,1,3,3,3,4,3,1,1,1,2,1,6,5,4)
m1 <- cbind(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6)

fa <- factanal(m1, factors=3,scores="regression")

fa$scores # the correct solution

fac <- m1 %*% loadings(fa) # the answer on your question
```

These are clearly different values.

Edit : This has to do with the fact that the Thomson regression scores are based on scaled variables, and take the correlation matrix into account. If you would calculate the scores by hand, you'd do :

```
> fac2 <- scale(m1) %*% solve(cor(m1)) %*% loadings(fa)
> all.equal(fa$scores,as.matrix(fac2))
[1] TRUE
```

For more information, see [this review](http://www.psy.ed.ac.uk/people/iand/Bartholomew%20%282009%29%20Br%20J%20Math%20Stat%20Psychol%20factor%20scores%20Thomson%20Spearman%20Bartlett.pdf)

And to show you why it is important : If you calculate the scores the "naive" way, your scores are actually correlated. And that is what you wanted to get rid of in the first place :

```
> round(cor(fac),2)
        Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
Factor1    1.00    0.79    0.81
Factor2    0.79    1.00    0.82
Factor3    0.81    0.82    1.00

> round(cor(fac2),2)
        Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
Factor1       1       0       0
Factor2       0       1       0
Factor3       0       0       1
```

Comment: Yes, that´s what I asked for. Is standardizing the only benefit of these scores created by regression? Calculating the ML matrix delivers pretty highly correlated variables (see edit of my question).

Comment: @ran2 : No, these scores have a bit more math behind them, which is sparsely explained in the help file of factanal. A more elaborate overview can be found in this paper: http://www.psy.ed.ac.uk/people/iand/Bartholomew%20%282009%29%20Br%20J%20Math%20Stat%20Psychol%20factor%20scores%20Thomson%20Spearman%20Bartlett.pdf

Comment: +1 For showing me that I need to use the scores parameter in factanal.  Thank you, @joris

Comment: Here is a [follow-up question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/43300/930) for you on Cross Validated :-)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't checked it manually, but here´s a way do it:

```
fa <-  factanal(mydf,3,rotation="varimax",scores="regression")
fa$scores
```

HTH someone else. Suggestions, corrections, improvements welcome!

Comment: using a promax rotation violates the assumption of uncorrelated scores. Although the interpretation _seems_ easier, the structure of the data has been changed profoundly. One has to be very, very careful using a non-orthogonal rotation.

Comment: Thx! very valuable input. I just mixed it up, I was only trying, interpretation doesn't get better with it. I just checked the robustness of my interpretation and posted the wrong line.

Answer (score 2):

Do you not want the `loadings` component?

```
loadings(fa)
```

See `?loadings` and `?factanal` to check that it is loadings you want. I find the terminology used so confusing at times, what with loadings, scores, ...

Comment: indeed it´s confusing. but what you suggest is equivalent to fa$loadings which like the "correlation" with a factor. What I want is a factor on a per observation basis.

Comment: I was meaning `mydf %*% loadings(fa)` is what I thought you wanted... And I see Joris has suggested such a thing in his answer.

Comment: Sorry Gavin – sometimes I just need a little extra help. I did see what you meant at first sight. Thx to Joris and your comment it´s clear and it´s the answer to my question :)

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked on [Psych SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/20404/generating-a-factor-score-for-an-individual-sample-using-r).

There, I provide a function in case you want to generate factor scores for new data.

---

I wrote the following function that takes the fit object returned by `factanal` and new data that you provide (e.g., a data frame or matrix with identical variable names).

```
score_new_data <- function(fit, data) {
    z <- as.matrix(scale(data[,row.names(fit$correlation)]))
    z %*% solve(fit$correlation, fit$loadings)
}
```

So for example,

```
bfi <- na.omit(bfi)
variables <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4")
data <- bfi[,variables]
fit <- factanal(data, factors = 2, scores = "regression", rotation = "varimax")
```

This is a typical factor analysis.

And now supply some new data along with the fit of the factor analysis:

```
score_new_data(fit, data[1:5, ])
```

And it generates the following:

```
> score_new_data(fit, data[1:5, ])
         Factor1    Factor2
61623  1.5022427  0.5457393
61629 -0.6817812 -0.9755466
61634 -0.2901822  0.1051234
61640  0.5429929 -0.4955180
61661 -1.0732722  0.8202019
```